# I'm trying to understand DFAs is my DFA correct in this question if not why?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I have the following alphat {0,1}.

I'm told to draw a DFA which fulfills the following: {w|w starts with 1 and ends in 0}

This is the DFA I came up with.

[image: DFA]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dfa is **incorrect**. 
To start, a dfa MUST define a transition for every node, including accepting nodes.

Anyhow, the current dfa would have accepted the language L = { w | w is a series of 1's and a single 0 at the end }

To correct this, you need to add another transition from B to A when it recieves 1 and a transition from B to itself when recieving 0. This is required to allow strings with 0 in the middle to also be accepted